# How would the world react to a dragon like species appearing?

Tags: magic, alternate-worlds

The species, in general, is large, the minimum size being the size of a large truck. The largest size it can get is unknown. The creature appears to defy laws of physics we known as well(so, if the creature could somehow be Godzilla sized, it wouldn't crush itself under its own weight.) 
They appear to be GoT styled dragons, varying in colour however most tend to be dark shades, varying blue colours.
 Most of them, once studied after the scenario, seem to have large wingspans and long tails, alongside varying horns (ram horns, deer horns, standard dragon horns, etc). The dragons are carnivores and will feed on anything, dead or alive. They usually tend to be alone, but can be seen joining up to take down large prey, or during feeding frenzies.

The scenario, now. A few hours before the scenario takes place, a few lucky undersea cameras capture movement of something moving up towards the surface. They're not able to capture the full body of the creature, however may see its tail.

At 2:00 am, Standard Eastern Time(however, you are free to convert this into whatever time later), some boats capture sight of something fast moving at the surface. In clearer parts of the water, some people report afterwards seeing a large body with large 'fins'. The creature does not stop its movement, and continues towards a designation.

Around one hour later, a small fishing boat has been reported vanished. Nothing out of the ordinary, correct? That was thought, until when investigators arrived, and discovered the many remains of the boat, no bodies found. The boat appeared to have exploded into several pieces. But our dear dragon friend is a long way away now.

30 minutes later, the dragon hits shore. You can choose what shore of whatever country/city it is. Immediately after landing, creature collapses, as if exhausted. The beach is empty, aside from three people who are frozen out of pure shock, like a deer trapped in headlights.

One of the people(dumb decision up ahead) chooses to move closer, and snaps a photo of it. Thinking it was dead, the person also decided not to turn flash off. The creature reacts to bright light by quickly awakening from whatever collapse it was in, and attacking the source, which goes 'crunch' soon after. The other two begin to scream and run off. Attracted to the loud noise, the creature begins to chase them. It reveals that it's not good at running on all fours. One person escapes, but the other trips and quickly falls into the jaws of the creature.

Our creature smells more humans, which is unfortunately the city. It takes its rampage up towards the city and begins to attack, at this point not even eating its prey: instead hunting for sport.

As far as resistance to guns and weaponry goes, the creature can surprisingly withstand tank projectiles, however, it does hurt if at a close range. Should humans find bullets that can pierce the scales of the creature, the creature, after some time, 'evolves' stronger scales to stand it. Essentially a; you get stronger weapons, I get stronger scales.

Intelligence wise, they learn with experience. Should the creature survive whatever battle it ran into, it teaches its offspring. However, most appear to have less than human intelligence, but a few have intelligence that can rival it, which have yet to be discovered.

Behaviour wise, the original appears to be aggressive, as do most of its species. But perps one capable of feeling human like emotion exist..

How long until the military responds to this creature? Should it be killed, the creature has an odd amount of hot steam escaping from its mouth, but it dies out fairly quickly. The wounds all over the body appeared to have lessened, suggesting it may be capable of regeneration, however a weaker form. The steam may suggest the creature is able to breathe fire, much like the stereotypical dragon. Or, it's body temperature is stunningly high.

For my original question, how do world leaders respond? How do civilians respond? How do different countries respond? How does society, as a whole respond? Basically, the reactions of everyone.

The time set for this is modern times. (Aka now.)

A few weeks after the original appearance, reports of all over the world say that these creatures are showing up all over the world, promoting to man that a new species may be appearing, and they're not friendly.

I would like to see any response to the reactions of different types of people or countries. The reaction to the first creature may differ, depending on what country its dropped into. You may answer some of the extra questions, such as the goals, or even add on some points of your own.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'm afraid questions asking how society would react to something are generally closed as either too broad or too opinion-based. Additionally, you seem to be asking multiple questions; please consider narrowing this down to just one question. Be sure to check out the help center and take the tour!

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Interesting concept, but asking how society would react is pretty much impossible - humans vary quite a lot and there are many aspects that would have to be considered. Normally how society reacts is a good point for just thinking about what is best in your story/game/... For questions on this site we need clear goals and ways to rate answers against each other (and there is a character limit of 30.000 for answers ;) ). If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about this site. Have fun!

Comment: I think I effectively answered the gist of this, because this can be paralleled with lions pretty easily. However, asking to define reactions down to individual people is madness

Comment: We would build giant robot mechs to battle the dragons obviously.

Comment: Rent the movie *[Reign of Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reign_of_Fire_(film))* for a better than average example of what would happen.

Comment: Hi Specsatat, and welcome to Worldbuilding! As has been mentioned already, asking how society would react to something is virtually always too broad, and unfortunately, I think this is another example of that. You may want to see our [interspecies-relationships tag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-relations); as you will note from the large percentage of those being closed, this is a subject that even experienced community members and site regulars find hard to narrow down and specify sufficiently for it to be answerable according to our standards.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by your question being put on hold, and please remember that closure is about the *question*, not about *you*. I do suggest reviewing the suggestions in [How to write the perfect question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/29) on [meta], as that has some tips on how to write questions that are less likely to end up closed. You might want to read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [try the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29). Above all, have fun!

Comment: @JBH ROF didn't depict mans reaction to the emergence of dragons only the aftermath which is smart because they avoided describing how the heck dragons managed to defeat fighter jets, Anti-aircraft munitions(flak rounds, .50cals, laser guided missiles, .etc). I don't care how tough the skin is, there is no terrestrially comparable genetic trait that would allow an organism to survive direct fire from the full spectrum of modern military munitions.

Comment: @anon, wait, you mean Matthew Broderick's *[Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_(1998_film))* LIED to me?  You mean hollywood LIES to me? SAY IT ISN"T SO!  :-)  I pointed out *Reign of Fire* because it's a useful POV for this kind of storyline.  Heck, if reality was a requirement of fiction, Harry Potter would never have existed.  :-p

Comment: Yeah but harry potter has that reality hack concept of magic so anything goes once that hits the fan.

Answer (score 2):

**What always happens when man meets a predator**

We would drive it to extinction

The likely scenario is, in response to large casualties governments and militaries would react without hesitation to eradicate the threat.

After civilian casualties have been reduced and urban areas protected. Conservationists may have a chance at convincing governments to limit their efforts and establish reserves where the predator could exist in peace. After all, we all want to see dragons just not be eaten or burned by them.

Sentient dragons would likely be welcomed in this scenario as they could be reasoned with to coexist with mankind. This would largely depend on the hate cycle though ( the cycle created from endless retaliation for death of loved ones) both from the dragons and humans.

But make no mistake, no society would accept uncontrollable predation of its constituents. Even Africans only tolerate lions to an extent. When lions cross they line they pay the price. However they tolerate lions because we want them to exist, we want to see them, we love their majesty even though they could end us in an instant.

Comment: So true! Just ask the wolves